# Twitter Social Login integration in Liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I want to integrate social login with Liferay login. I am done with Linkedin and google but I can't find any liferay-hook for twitter on marketplace.
I have downloaded:

- https://web.liferay.com/es/marketplace/-/mp/application/41130997
- https://github.com/sergiogonzalez/twitter-login-hook

but both are not working.

can any one suggest me from where I can download it?

Comment: If you'd elaborate on "not working", stackoverflow might be the right place. If you're asking for a link, it's not.

Comment: @vinita Can you please let us know about the issue which you are facing or any error log

Comment: I have dowmloaded the hook from ,

https://github.com/sergiogonzalez/twitter-login-hook

and successfully deployed it without error but when i logged in with twitter it goes to twitter login page and after login it does not comes back to the liferay site..I have checked the callback URL its completely ok...so I am not able to find out the issue.